# Unable to publish from Visual Studio if another user already published the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

The scenario is as follows: User A (Microsoft AD Account) publishes an application, with the publish setting set on `File System`, to a shared network folder. The file publish options are set to `Delete all existing files prior to publish`. After the publish is completed, the shared network folder contains files and folders.

User B (also Microsoft AD Account) now needs to do a publish (running the same publish profile configured) as user A is not available to do the publish, but he gets `Access is denied` when the process tries to delete the existing folders, however, all the files have been deleted (as per the publish option setting).

When checking the security permissions on the remaining folders, it seems that user A is set as the owner of the remaining folders, thus throwing the `Access is denied` error for user B.

If user A manually deletes the folders in the shared network folder, user B is able to run the publish without a hitch.

Are there some other publishing settings that needs to be checked in order for multiple users to be able to publish to the same shared network folder?

Comment: would be able you define the security/permissions for the parent folder?

Comment: I already had this issue. The owner of the folder has to make this one updatable by other users (he has to add some persons as admin to the folder).